# Why is my program saying Reagan is not defined even though I got the name in double quotes, I mean it's not a variable?

Tags: python

```
print ("This is a simple login")
while True:
    enter = input("Enter the password for this computer: ")
    if enter == "Reagan":
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("Your Login is successful")
    else:
        print ("Password didn't match! ")
```

**UPDATE**

This is the output of the program when run from the terminal:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Python Programming/Practice/for loops.py"        
This is a simple login Enter 
the password for this computer: Reagan 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python Programming/Practice/for loops.py", 
line 3, in <module> enter = input("Enter the password for this computer: ") File "<string>",
line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Reagan' is not defined Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Python 2? Use `raw_input` not `input`

Comment: you code is wrong, missing indentation !!

Answer (score 1):

You need `raw_input()`

```
import time
print ("This is a simple login")
while True:
    enter = raw_input("Enter the password for this computer: ")
    if enter == "Reagan":
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("Your Login is successful")
    else:
        print ("Password didn't match! ")
```